# Swift Package Manager cannot find a neighboring folder/class in Sources

Tags: swift-package-manager

**Goal:** To access neighboring folder/classes within the source folder.

**Scenario:** I have two classes:

1. RicPackage (default) and
2. Apple

The 'RicPackage' was *auto-generated* upon the creation of the Swift Package 'RicPackage'.   
I want to expand and try to access other folders w/classes autonomously.

Here's the manifest that I'm working on:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "RicPackage",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "RicPackage",
            targets: ["RicPackage"]),
        .library(
            name: "Apple",
            targets: ["Apple"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "RicPackage",
            dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "Apple",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "RicPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["RicPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

I want to be able to access 'Apple' and other such folders independently from the host program.

Here's the Apple source code:

```
import Foundation

class Apple {
    public private(set) var text = "Hello from Apple!"

    public init() {
    }
    
    public func eat() -> String {
        print("Inside Eat Apple")
        return "Hello from Eat Apple."
    }
}
```

Here's the test.
Once I get this to work,  I'll try to access it from the host application.

[image]

I believe that classes & functions must be 'pubic' to be seen.

**Questions:**

1. What am I doing wrong with the package manifest file?
2. Must a target class file have the same name as its folder container?
   ... for example: 'Apple/Apple.swift'.

Comment: In `RicPackageTests`, I'd say it also need `Apple` as a dependency: `dependencies: ["RicPackage"]` => `dependencies: ["RicPackage", "Apple"]`, else how would it have knowledge of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in `RicPackageTest`, you can't find `Apple`. Is there an `import` missing? Not necessarily, you won't find it either.

It's because in the way that `RicPackageTest` is constructed it has no knowledge of the `Apple` package.

You wrote:

```
.testTarget(
    name: "RicPackageTests",
    dependencies: ["RicPackage"]),
```

That's what's missing, you aren't saying that `RicPackageTests` should "depend" (ie "knows of") `Apple` package.

So you should do:

```
.testTarget(
    name: "RicPackageTests",
    dependencies: ["RicPackage", "Apple"]),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Larme for correctly answering my novice question.

Here's the solution:

1. Need dependency:
   [image]

2. Need reference in test:

[image]